# centos webserver missing memory

Tags: centos, web-server, web-hosting, linux

So I just started a new job and one of my tasks is to move our hosting to a new cheaper server, i'm trying to spec out the new server but I'm a little unsure on the amount of memory I will actually need.

Our current server has 4 gigs of RAM and when I use the top command to check out what's running it shows that 3 of the 4 gig is being used, but the system processes only show tasks using very small amounts of memory, the highest used is at 0.7.

first of all, is using 3 out of 4 gigs of RAM usual for a server that hosts less than 20 sites (most of which are fairly small scale)
if not where has all my memory gone?

Some Server Info:
OS: CentOS 5.5
RAM: 4gig
CPU: Quad Core Intel Xeon (2GHz per core)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, it's a classic question. See http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ for an answer.

Comment: thanks, I just did some googleing and found out what was going, cheers guys

Comment: accepted duplicate, jealousy == downvote

Answer (score 1):

Read http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ which will explain true memory usage to you.

Answer (score 0):

It's gone into cache and buffers. Use `free`, and check the second line.

Comment: total    used    free   shared   buffers  cached
Mem:     4194480  3290524 903956     0     205332    2656604
-/+ buffers/cache:     428588    3765892
Swap:      6258680          8    6258672

thats what I get out. so I do actually have over 3 gig free then?
which should mean I can go for a lower spec with the new webserver?

Comment: Your system uses approx. 420M of your memory. The rest are caches and buffers which will be freed if an application needs more memory. Just answer yourself a question: Is unused RAM really useful?

Comment: yeah, it makes sense when you say it like that, thanks